# Microwave lcd display works but lost color.instead numbers are now greyish.

Tags: display, microwave, backlight

[image: display is still usable as values change in real time, but lost color.]

Microwave is completely usable. And still goes to sleep to power save after some time. Problem is although display updates and works as it should...the values are now shown in a greyish color instead bright colored just like normal 7 segment sort of displays.

Comment: Back-light not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the display backlight has failed. The backlight would be provided by an electroluminescent or LED module probably, either of which might have burnt out or become disconnected.

Some 7-segment displays have a separate illuminated LED for each segment - these can be identified by their black plastic facing with cut out holes for each segment. But the display you pictured uses a single backlight for the entire display. The display is implemented as a normally-opaque layer over top of the backlight, with LCD segments which can be selectively made translucent, to allow the light to shine through. So, it's possible for the backlight to fail, but for the display to still be readable, since the translucent segments and opaque background *reflect* ambient light differently. But of course, it will be difficult to read in low-light conditions.